# QlikView blocks Scripts folder for asp.net / mvc pages on same server

Tags: asp.net, iis, qlikview

We have a brand new WinServer2k8R2 with IIS7.5. Asp.Net site on it would not display any javascript files. Narrowed it down to QlikView.

When QlikView is installed on our server, it takes over the /Scripts/ folder on *every* website in IIS.

Is there any way to stop it from doing this, or restrict to only one website instead of all?

Comment: Did you install QlikView Webserver or did you choose IIS-based-installation? Regards
Stefan

Comment: This was a year and a half ago, I can't remember. I no longer work at the company where I used this ... hope it is not an issue any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May have found a possible fix:

go to C:\ProgramData\QlikTech\WebServer\config.xml

and change the port on the DefaultUrl to anything other than 80: e.g.

```
http://_:8080/
```

unfortuanately I have not yet got QlikView working again